# Collision detection for every shape (2D)

Tags: algorithm, collision-detection, game-engine

I am currenty making a game which the user can make shapes(it can be every shape the user want exept for curves) and get them to interact with each other.I need a accurate collision detection algorithm that can run fast(somthing like 150 poligons at max), i managed to imploment [SAT](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/collision-detection-using-the-separating-axis-theorem--gamedev-169)
but it seems to fall apart at more complex shapes.Can someone direct me to relevent algorithms for my situation?

Answer (score 0):

SAT is intended for convex polygons.

In general case (your shapes can be concave) you can hold edge list for polygons and check for edge intersection with [sweep line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm). *(Note also that one polygon may fully contain other)*

In some situations it is worth to create convex hull for every shape and check for hull intersection with SAT. If it occurs, then use more advanced algorithm to check whether real intersection does exist.

Comment: My end goal is to use this algorithm when movement acours,Do you think sweep line can be enough for that? maybe i can devide the shape to triangles and use SAT.